# Integral point on certain cubic surfaces and rational parametric solutions

Tags: number-theory, algebraic-geometry, diophantine-equations

The motivation of the following question comes from the Problem **D4** in the book "*unsolved problems in number theory*" by Richard Guy.

No integral points on the surface $S:x^3+y^3+z^3=3$ is known other than $(1,1,1),(4,4,-5)$ and their permutations. Although integral points are sparse on the surface, it is well known that we can construct a large number of rational points from a given rational point $(a,b,c)$. Any rational line passing through $(a,b,c)$ must intersect $S$ at two points $P,\bar{P}$, which are conjugate to each other over some quadratic field $K$. The tangent plane passing through $P$($\bar{P}$) intersects S at some rational plane curve $C$ over $K$. Join any point on $C$ over $K$ and its conjugate by line, and it will intersect $S$ at a rational point.

**Question:** The procedure constructs a family of rational points. Is there any way to find out an integral point in such families?

Comment: If there were, I imagine someone would have found it. But sometimes you can prove that these constructions are guaranteed to make denominators bigger, and if that's the case you can prove that you don't get integer points.

Comment: @GerryMyerson: Hmm. The denominators in the constructions are polynomials of (at least) four variables, and I'm not sure what an obstruction will be to prevent these polynomials from taking small values.

Comment: @yzhao: Look at the theory of heights of points on elliptic curves, as explained in Silverman (for example).  This might give some hint of what happens in the cubic surface case.  And then Manin's book probably discusses this as well.  (Have you looked at it?)

Comment: @guy-in-seoul: I did take a look at Manin's book on cubic forms, and the construction is just the one he introduces in the introduction. But I am not sure if he ever talks about something about integral points in his book.

Comment: @yzhao: It's a long time since I looked at his book.  Does he discuss heights at all?  (And maybe heights aren't really relevant; they can't distinguish between a numerator or a deminominator I guess.  It just seemed worth thinking about.)

Comment: @guy-in-seoul: He discuss about heights in the last chapter in his book.